# configure NProgress slim processbar for Arabic site right to left

Tags: jquery, css

How to configure NProgress(NProgress.js) slim processbar for Arabic site right to left like youtube processbar start from right to left..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the script:

```
function toBarPerc(n) {
    return 100 - (n * 100);
}
```

and add this CSS:

```
#nprogress .bar {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 0;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLx8f9xa/).